# How to Use Content Negotiation in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, restful-url, content-negotiation

I am trying to expose my data via Rest Api in difetents formats (xml,json,rdf,jsonld) and I am using Spring-Data-Rest-Framework and I know that it is posible using  @RequestMapping in the Controller, buts in Spring Data Rest I only have a entity and a repository that use @RepositoryRestResource notation that does not support @RequestMapping notation.

Can somebody explain me the way to achieve expose my data in difente formats using Spring Data Rest ?

I would like to expecifice the format at the end of the URL like ( ?format=json or  ?format=xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#representations.mapping

> Currently, only JSON representations are supported. Other
>   representation types can be supported in the future by adding an
>   appropriate converter and updating the controller methods with the
>   appropriate content-type.

You would have to build your own converter for XML or other types. As well the standard way to define content type is in the `Accept` header. If you want to use an override then you need to add a filter to read the query parameter and set the header.